# Save Picture Box Image to PDF file

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms, save

I'm using WinForms. In my form i have a picturebox. I want to know how to save the image in the picturebox to a pdf. So far i have this code, but i seem to get an error when i open the saved file to check if the picture really turned into a pdf.

```
    private void Save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if(save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(save.FileName);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: To directly create a PDF (as opposed to printing to a PDF printer driver) you will need one of the [PDF libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+create+pdf&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=NVusVpPQD8byO9vYltgL#q=c%23%20pdf%20library)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System.Drawing.Image.Save() method used in your code can only save to a limited number of file types, such as BMP, TIFF and JPEG. The way your code is calling it, you will probably end up with a TIFF file even if you call it filename.PDF. Like TaW commented, this method cannot save to PDF and you will need to use an external tool for that.